# How to see broken file writes with node.js

Tags: node.js, file, fs

My english is not so good so I hope to be clear.

Just for sake of curiosity I want to test multiple concurrent(*) file writes on the same file and see that t produce errors.

The manual is clear on that:

> Note that it is unsafe to use `fs.writeFile` multiple times on the same
>   file without waiting for the callback. For this scenario,
>   `fs.createWriteStream` is strongly recommended.

So if I write a relatively big amount of data into a file and in the while it is still writing I'm call another file write on the same file without waiting for the callback.. I'm expecting some sort of error.

I tried to wrote a small example to test this situation but I can't manage to see any errors.

```
"use strict";
const fs = require('fs');
const writeToFile = (filename, data) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile(filename, data, { flag: 'a' }, err => {
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        }
        return resolve();
    });
});
const getChars = (num, char) => {
    let result = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        result += char;
    }
    return result + '\n';
};
const k = 10000000;
const data0 = getChars(k, 0);
const data1 = getChars(k, 1);
writeToFile('test1', data0)
    .then(() => console.log('0 written'))
    .catch(e => console.log('errors in write 0'));
writeToFile('test1', data1)
    .then(() => console.log('1 written'))
    .catch(e => console.log('errors in write 1'));
```

To test it instead of open the file with some editor (that is a little bit slow in my box) I use a linux command to see the end of the first buffer and the beginning of the second buffer (and that they do not overlap):

```
tail -c 10000010 test1 | grep 0
```

But I'm not sure it is the right way to test it.

Just to be clear I'm with node v6.2.2, and mac 10.11.6.

Does anyone over there can point me a small sketch that uses `fs.writeFile` that produce a wrong output?

(*) concurrent = don't wait for the end of one file write to begin the next one